# Number of max connection per server in Htmlunit?

Tags: java, htmlunit, headless-browser

How much is the number of max connection per server in htmunit? 
I know it depends on the browser but how to change it؟

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection](https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HttpWebConnection.java) and check for maxConnPerRoute.